# Kotlin generics with nullable types

Tags: generics, kotlin

I want to create a function with the next semantics:

```
fun myFunction(input: <String? or String>): <Same type as input>
```

And use it in the next cases:

```
val a1: String
val b1: String = myFunction(a1)

val a2: String?
val b2: String? = myFunction(a1)
```

How to define such a function?

I tried something like:

```
fun <T: String?> myFunction(value: T): T {
    if (value == null) {
        return null
    }
    return value
}
```

But I have compile time errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest just making two overloads:

```
@JvmName("myFunctionNonNull")
fun myFunction(value: String): String {
    ...
}

fun myFunction(value: String?): String? = value?.let(::myFunction)
```

Failing that, I think the best you can do is to add casts and convince yourself they are safe:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T: String?> myFunction(value: T): T {
    if (value == null) {
        return null as T
    }
    return value as T
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the return type as nullable:

```
fun <T: String?> myFunction(value: T): T? {
    if (value == null) {
        return null
    }
    return value
}
```

This basically means that you don't need to have a generic function, at least not for the `String` type that is `final`.

Edit: why it cannot work like you want?
Let's suppose we follow your signature, but with a different function:

```
fun <T : String?> myFunction(value: T): T {
    return null
}
```

You could call this function like this:

```
myFunction("banana")
```

The parameter is not `null` but the function is still returning `null`!
Solely using the type system the compiler cannot ensure that you will return `null` only when the input is `null`.

Maybe you want to have a look at [Kotlin contracts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew13.html#contracts).

Comment: But this function returns always nullable type. I want not null type if the input was not null.

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible solely using the type system. See my edited answer for an explanation