# Kotlin return type inference based on parameter type

Tags: kotlin, types, parameters, type-inference, return-type

I have a function:

```kotlin
object CliUtils {
    var skipOptionalArgs = false

    fun readOptional(variableName: String, defaultValue: String? = null): String? {
        if (skipOptionalArgs) return defaultValue
        print("Provide the $variableName (optional${if (defaultValue != null) ", default: $defaultValue" else ""}): ")
        return readln().takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() } ?: defaultValue
    }
}
```

When I use this function like so...

```kotlin
val inputName = readOptional("input name", "Input")
```

...the the type of `inputName` is `String?`. Due to the `defaultValue` of `"Input"` that I gave though, I know that the variable is not `null`.

I could use a double exclamation mark like so:

```kotlin
val inputName = readOptional("input name", "Input")!!
```

But I feel that there should be a way to define the `readOptional` function so that this return type of String could be inferred, without the use of double exclamation mark. I thought of contracts, but to my knowledge contracts can only refer to parameters, not to the return type. I also thought of generics to link the type of the `defaultValue` parameter type to the return type, but I couldn't get that to work with its nullability.

Is there any way to make kotlin understand that if `defaultValue != null` that the return value also isn't null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with generics:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T : String?> readOptional(variableName: String, defaultValue: T = null as T): T {
    if (skipOptionalArgs) return defaultValue
    print("Provide the $variableName (optional${if (defaultValue != null) ", default: $defaultValue" else ""}): ")
    return (readln().takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }  ?: defaultValue) as T
}
```

The caller side doesn't need the evil `!!` check anymore:

```
val inputName: String = readOptional("input name", "Input")

val inputNameNullable: String? = readOptional("input name", null)

val inputNameDefaultNullable: String? = readOptional("input name")
```

But the price we have to pay is the **unchecked cast**. This is, because the compiler cannot ensure that the method returns the not null default paramater in every condition.

So we made it comfortable for the caller site to use all variants without the additional check. But as mentioned the compiler can't prevent us in using it wrong. It's stillt possible to additional set the (wrong) generic type or let it infer the wrong from the val type:

```kotlin
val inputNameDefaultTypedWrong: String = readOptional<String>("input name")
val inputNameDefaultNullableWrongInferred: String = readOptional("input name")
```

**Edit**: This can be also solved in combination with an additional method overload, like mentioned by [@Tenfour04](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76344477/4198170):

```kotlin
fun readOptional(variableName: String): String? = readOptional(variableName, null)
```

My idea and more explanations can be also found here:
[Kotlin generics with nullable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57185646/kotlin-generics-with-nullable-types)

Comment: Great write up from you and @Tenfour04. I forgot to cast the default value of `null` to `T`, so that's why I didn't get the generics working myself.
One curious thing though is that if I don't cast the return value to `T`, I get the error: `Type mismatch. Required T, found String`. I thought it would have found `String?`, rather than `String`. If I put it in a variable it also resolves to `String?`, so why does the type mismatch specify `String` rather than `String?`?

Comment: Because the compiler is not so sophisticated that it rules out possibilities resulting from final types. We know that logically it must be String because String has no subclasses, but the compiler doesn’t consider that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use generics for this, but to do it safely I think you would have to have an overload for the null default version.

```
fun <T: String?> readOptional(variableName: String, defaultValue: T): T {
    if (skipOptionalArgs) return defaultValue
    print("Provide the $variableName (optional${if (defaultValue != null) ", default: $defaultValue" else ""}): ")
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return (readln().takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() } ?: defaultValue) as T
}

fun readOptional(variableName: String): String? = readOptional(variableName, null)
```

Comment: Correction on the `readOptional` function without default value: you need to specify `null as String?` here, because otherwise the return type would be `Nothing?` and you would get a class cast exception if the user input isn't empty.

Comment: @RikSchaaf, I’m away from computer so can’t check it, but I think this should be inferring the null to be a `String?` because the `String?` return value causes it to infer `<String?>` for the type of the function call.

Comment: Ah you might be right. When I tested it, I didn't explicitly define the return type, so I had to specify `null as String?`, but you might be right that if you specify the return type, you don't need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is the overload function:

```
fun readOptional(variableName: String, defaultValue: String) =
    readOptional(variableName, defaultValue as String?)!!
```