# Kotlin return type inference based on multiple parameter types

Tags: kotlin, types, parameters, type-inference, return-type

As a followup to [Kotlin return type inference based on parameter type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76344278/kotlin-return-type-inference-based-on-parameter-type) and incorporating its answer, here is my next question. Consider the following code:

```kotlin
enum class Usage {
    REQUIRED,
    OPTIONAL,
    UNSUPPORTED
}

object CliUtils {
    var skipOptionalArgs = false
    
    fun test() {
        val readForUsageRequired1: String = readForUsage("var1", Usage.REQUIRED) // Doesn't compile
        val readForUsageOptional1: String? = readForUsage("var2", Usage.OPTIONAL)
        val readForUsageUnsupported1: String? = readForUsage("var3", Usage.UNSUPPORTED)
        val readForUsageRequired2: String = readForUsage("var1", Usage.REQUIRED, null as String?) // Doesn't compile
        val readForUsageOptional2: String? = readForUsage("var2", Usage.OPTIONAL, null as String?)
        val readForUsageUnsupported2: String? = readForUsage("var3", Usage.UNSUPPORTED, null as String?)
        val readForUsageRequired3: String = readForUsage("var1", Usage.REQUIRED, "default1") // Doesn't compile
        val readForUsageOptional3: String = readForUsage("var2", Usage.OPTIONAL, "default2") // Doesn't compile
        val readForUsageUnsupported3: String? = readForUsage("var3", Usage.UNSUPPORTED, "default3")
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun <T: String?> readForUsage(variableName: String, usage: Usage, defaultValue: T) = when (usage) {
        Usage.REQUIRED -> readRequired(variableName) as T
        Usage.OPTIONAL -> readOptional(variableName, defaultValue)
        Usage.UNSUPPORTED -> null
    }
    fun readForUsage(variableName: String, usage: Usage): String? = readForUsage(variableName, usage, null as String?)

    fun <T: String?> readOptional(variableName: String, defaultValue: T): T {
        if (skipOptionalArgs) return defaultValue
        print("Provide the $variableName (optional${if (defaultValue != null) ", default: $defaultValue" else ""}): ")
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return (readln().takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() } ?: defaultValue) as T
    }
    fun readOptional(variableName: String): String? = readOptional(variableName, null)

    fun readRequired(variableName: String): String {
        while (true) {
            print("Provide the $variableName: ")
            val value = readln()
            if (value.isNotEmpty()) {
                return value
            }
            println("Invalid $variableName provided!")
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, what I want is for the function's return value to be inferred to the following:

- For `Usage.REQUIRED`, `readForUsage(...)` will return a `String`
- For `Usage.UNSUPPORTED`, `readForUsage(...)` will return a `String?`
- For `Usage.OPTIONAL`, `readForUsage(...)` will return a type based on the provided `defaultValue`, which is either `String?` or `String` (similar to how the `readOptional(...)` is implemented).

The problem is that I can't figure out how I can make the return value of `readForUsage(...)` dependent on both the `defaultValue` parameter AND the `usage` parameter.

Any idea on how to rewrite `readForUsage(...)` so that `test()` compiles?

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible. The overload it resolves is based on the function name and argument *types*, not values. Your parameter value is resolved at runtime but the function overload and return type are resolved at compile time.

Comment: @Tenfour04 ok, so this would require a major extension to the contract feature to make implications for return types possible based on parameters, right? 
From what I understand, right now contract only supports implications for the parameters based on the return value, not the other way around.

Comment: I don’t know how it could possibly work in any way whatsoever, since argument values are resolved at runtime and return types are resolved at compile time. How could you possibly make the argument value resolve at compile time? It doesn’t make sense. It’s an argument so it could be any value that matches the type. A contract can help with smart casting, but there’s nothing to cast because you’re not using argument types to distinguish the return types. You’re using argument values.

Comment: Since the value is an enum, it might be possible to associate each of the limited number of values with a type. That way, based on that associated type, some kind of hint could be given to aid in the  smart casting.

Comment: Since enums don't support generics, it would probably not work with the Usage enum, but if a sealed class is used instead, it might be possible. I'm going to see how far I can get using that.

Comment: You could overload the function with each one taking a different child class of sealed class as the argument type. They don’t have to be in a sealed class either if they are just `object`s. But ultimately it seems pointless. Why use an argument to distinguish between functions when you can do it by naming the functions differently? It is basically creating different functions that have to be called using an extra argument.

Comment: The reason is because I want them to share the same method syntax. The gain is indeed small, but it was more an exercise to learn about smart casting and how to work around its limitations, rather than a practical use case.

Comment: Also, the reason I mentioned sealed classes is so that I don't have to provide a default when case, because it being sealed makes it exhaustive. This therefore would mimic the enum that it used to be better.

Answer (score 1):

To make this possible I had to change the Usage enum into a sealed class. Initially I tried this:

```kotlin
sealed interface Usage<T: String?> {
    object REQUIRED : Usage<String>
    object OPTIONAL : Usage<String?>
    object UNSUPPORTED : Usage<Nothing?>
}

object CliUtils {
    var skipOptionalArgs = false
    
    fun test() {
        val readForUsageRequired1: String = readForUsage("var1", Usage.REQUIRED)
        val readForUsageOptional1: String? = readForUsage("var2", Usage.OPTIONAL)
        val readForUsageUnsupported1: Nothing? = readForUsage("var3", Usage.UNSUPPORTED)
        val readForUsageUnknown1: String? = readForUsage("var4", Some.OTHER.usageSource)

        val readForUsageRequired2: String = readForUsage("var1", Usage.REQUIRED, null as String?)
        val readForUsageOptional2: String? = readForUsage("var2", Usage.OPTIONAL, null as String?)
        val readForUsageUnsupported2: Nothing? = readForUsage("var3", Usage.UNSUPPORTED, null as String?)
        val readForUsageUnknown2: String? = readForUsage("var4", Some.OTHER.usageSource, null as String?)

        val readForUsageRequired3: String = readForUsage("var1", Usage.REQUIRED, "default1")
        val readForUsageOptional3: String = readForUsage("var2", Usage.OPTIONAL, "default2")
        val readForUsageUnsupported3: Nothing? = readForUsage("var3", Usage.UNSUPPORTED, "default3")
        val readForUsageUnknown3: String? = readForUsage("var4", Some.OTHER.usageSource,"default4")
    }

    fun <T: String?> readForUsage(variableName: String, usage: Usage<String>, defaultValue: T) = readRequired(variableName)
    fun <T: String?> readForUsage(variableName: String, usage: Usage<String?>, defaultValue: T) = readOptional(variableName, defaultValue)
    fun <T: String?> readForUsage(variableName: String, usage: Usage<Nothing?>, defaultValue: T) =  null
    fun <T: String?> readForUsage(variableName: String, usage: Usage<*>, defaultValue: T) = when (usage) {
        Usage.REQUIRED -> readRequired(variableName)
        Usage.OPTIONAL -> readOptional(variableName, defaultValue)
        Usage.UNSUPPORTED -> null
    }

    fun readForUsage(variableName: String, usage: Usage<String>): String = readForUsage(variableName, usage, null as String?)
    fun readForUsage(variableName: String, usage: Usage<String?>): String? = readForUsage(variableName, usage, null as String?)
    fun readForUsage(variableName: String, usage: Usage<Nothing?>): Nothing? = readForUsage(variableName, usage, null as String?)
    fun readForUsage(variableName: String, usage: Usage<*>): String? = readForUsage(variableName, usage, null as String?)
}
```

This however gave compiler errors for the JVM target due to overloading issues with generic type parameters. This was solved using the following change:

```kotlin
sealed interface Usage<T: String?> {
    object REQUIRED : Usage<String>
    object OPTIONAL : Usage<String?>
    object UNSUPPORTED : Usage<Nothing?>
}

object CliUtils {
    var skipOptionalArgs = false
    
    fun test() {
        val readForUsageRequired1: String = readForUsage("var1", Usage.REQUIRED)
        val readForUsageOptional1: String? = readForUsage("var2", Usage.OPTIONAL)
        val readForUsageUnsupported1: Nothing? = readForUsage("var3", Usage.UNSUPPORTED)
        val readForUsageUnknown1: String? = readForUsage("var4", Some.OTHER.usageSource)

        val readForUsageRequired2: String = readForUsage("var1", Usage.REQUIRED, null as String?)
        val readForUsageOptional2: String? = readForUsage("var2", Usage.OPTIONAL, null as String?)
        val readForUsageUnsupported2: Nothing? = readForUsage("var3", Usage.UNSUPPORTED, null as String?)
        val readForUsageUnknown2: String? = readForUsage("var4", Some.OTHER.usageSource, null as String?)

        val readForUsageRequired3: String = readForUsage("var1", Usage.REQUIRED, "default1")
        val readForUsageOptional3: String = readForUsage("var2", Usage.OPTIONAL, "default2")
        val readForUsageUnsupported3: Nothing? = readForUsage("var3", Usage.UNSUPPORTED, "default3")
        val readForUsageUnknown3: String? = readForUsage("var4", Some.OTHER.usageSource,"default4")
    }

    fun <T: String?> readForUsage(variableName: String, usage: Usage.REQUIRED, defaultValue: T) = readRequired(variableName)
    fun <T: String?> readForUsage(variableName: String, usage: Usage.OPTIONAL, defaultValue: T) = readOptional(variableName, defaultValue)
    fun <T: String?> readForUsage(variableName: String, usage: Usage.UNSUPPORTED, defaultValue: T) =  null
    fun <T: String?> readForUsage(variableName: String, usage: Usage<*>, defaultValue: T) = when (usage) {
        Usage.REQUIRED -> readRequired(variableName)
        Usage.OPTIONAL -> readOptional(variableName, defaultValue)
        Usage.UNSUPPORTED -> null
    }

    fun readForUsage(variableName: String, usage: Usage.REQUIRED): String = readForUsage(variableName, usage, null as String?)
    fun readForUsage(variableName: String, usage: Usage.OPTIONAL): String? = readForUsage(variableName, usage, null as String?)
    fun readForUsage(variableName: String, usage: Usage.UNSUPPORTED): Nothing? = readForUsage(variableName, usage, null as String?)
    fun readForUsage(variableName: String, usage: Usage<*>): String? = readForUsage(variableName, usage, null as String?)
}
```